# Qt mousePressEvent left button

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qtwidgets

I am using Qt but have run into a problem.

I want to register when the mouse is pressed and released on a `QTableWidget`. There are signals only for pressed, not released. Therefore I use `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` instead.

MyWidget.h

```
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
```

MyWidget.cpp

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Pressed";
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Released";
}
```

It prints "Released" when the left, right or middle mouse button is released over the table. However, it prints "Pressed" only when the right or middle button is pressed.

What could be wrong? How can I register when the left button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell widget probably consumes the `mousePressEvent` on the left mouse button, so you (the parent widget) are not receiving it.

Comment: Not a cell in this case, but another widget yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) of `QMouseEvent`, it is said that:

> A mouse event contains a special accept flag that indicates whether the receiver wants the event. You should call ignore() if the mouse event is not handled by your widget. A mouse event is propagated up the parent widget chain until a widget accepts it with accept(), or an event filter consumes it.

Because of that, we can suppose that probably the events you mentioned are consumed by some other actors.

It would help knowing who are those actors.

Comment: It seems that another widget consumed the event, yes. I wasn't able to solve it with ignore() but in another way, as described below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution (with help from the other answers):

There was a QFrame on top of the widget that consumed the event. I didn't think of that since it worked for the other buttons. It was solved by:

```
ui->frame->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, true);
```

Comment: Allright. NB if some answers actually helped you to solve your problem, you can express your gratitude by upvoting them :-)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the code of conduct for the forum, I'm new here.